# Active button not working (ADMIN LTE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using admin LTE template for admin side. When I will go to other page the button of that page will not be active. what I observe the way to active that button is the  must be  and also the li inside the  must be  
how can i do it using jquery

```
<li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
       <span> Manage Catalog</span>
       <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
       </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
       <li><a href="<?= base_url() .'administrator/products' ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Products</a></li>
       <li><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Discount/Promos</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

First give id for the "li" tags, for an instance, productMenu and DiscountMenu

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
     <li id="productMenu"><a href="<?= base_url() .'administrator/products' ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Products</a></li>
     <li id="DiscountMenu"><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Discount/Promos</a></li>
</ul>
```

script code to be added in icons.html:

```
<script>
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    if(path.indexOf("icons.html")!==-1){
        $("#DiscountMenu").addClass("active");
        $("#productMenu").removeClass("active");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**please try this**

```
<li class="treeview active">
<a href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
   <span> Manage Catalog</span>
   <span class="pull-right-container">
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
   </span>
</a>
<ul class="treeview-menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="<?= base_url() .'administrator/products' ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Products</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```